# Where can I share useful but unpolished code / hacks?

Tags: package-writing, sourcecode

During the course of writing my thesis I've come up with loads of useful macros and hacks and implemented them for my own use. For a few of them I've actually written and published packages. But others are unfinished, unpolished, undocumented or otherwise unsuitable for CTAN.

I've come to realize that I may never have the time to turn them all into proper packages. But they have been quite useful to me, and might be useful to others. I would certainly be willing to put them online with minimal descriptions. People could copy/paste them; perhaps package them up in my stead.

TeX.se is the most active TeX community I know. But as a Q&A site, it is not suitable for sharing code-snippets. I guess I could artificially create questions and answers around them, but that feels a bit silly.

**Question:** Is there a place to put (references to) my TeX code where many interested users / package-authors could find them?

Here's an incomplete list of the kind of code I mean:

- Extensions to `\cref`, such as **(1)** `\crefOr` to typeset "Equation 1, 2 or 3"  **(2)** `\crefPrevNext` to typeset things like "the previous section", "this section" or "the next section" when appropriate, and otherwise falls back to "Section 3.2" (also works for chapters, etc.) and **(3)** `\MyCrefAlias`, which globally makes one label-type an alias to another (also works with ranges).
- Convenience commands for locally manipulating word-stretch/shrink.
- A number of tikz commands to draw (fragments of) Venn diagrams.
- A package to automatically generate chapter/section labels based on the directory structure.

Comment: You may want to share this material on some code hosting web place, see [Who has a GitHub, Bitbucket, other code profile?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3821/who-has-a-github-bitbucket-other-code-profile)